# Like layout-sw600dp,alternative for drawable

Tags: android

My question is straight forward and simple, Like there is layout-sw600dp,values-sw600dp, for layout and values respectively, what is there for drawable folder in relative to size of screen.

I read in various document that if we want to use any screen more than or equal to 7 inches we can use layout-sw600dp folder, and for any lesser screen size device, layout folder will be taken into consideration. So how we can make use of same concept for images also. Right now there are ldpi, mdpi, hdpi folder, but images are taken in accordance of screen density not with screen size.Now if I am developing an app which work both on device and phone, what should be my probable approach for images.

Thanks in advance, please guide me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can also use the same concept for drawable like drawable-sw600dp,drawable-sw600dp-mdpi etc. I have used this in my application .

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% on this one, but I think you can also use the same convention with drawables. Try `drawable-sw600dp-hdpi` or something similar. Though I also do have a few questions you may want to answer before proceeding:

1. Why would you want a different image (not resolution) for a bigger screen size?
2. As you already know, a 7-inch device would be using the layout-sw600dp folder, so why not have a different name for a different drawable? That would look a lot cleaner, imo.

Comment: Actually I want to use different resolution images only and after using drwable-sw600dp folder also images are taken from default folder only